# How to delay fetch() until website has finished loading dynamic content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, fetch-api, dynamic-content

I have a chrome extension. Whenever the user clicks the extension's button it will download the source of the following URL: "smmry.com/(the user's current active tab's url)"

I'm using the following javascript code to download the source of the URL in the form of a html file. This code is currently run whenever the user clicks my extension's button (The variable URL is a hypothetical URL that my extension could download. In this case, the user would actually be browsing cnn.com/(path_to_news_article), but the extension would be downloading: smmry.com/https://www.cnn.com/(path_to_news_article)):

```
let URL = 'https://smmry.com/https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/01/politics/ronald-kessler-jake-tapper-interview/index.html#&SM_LENGTH=7'
    fetch(URL)
        .then((resp) => resp.text())
        .then(responseText => {
           download("website_source.html", responseText)
        })

function download(filename, text) {

    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Here's the source of the webpage: https://smmry.com/https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/01/politics/ronald-kessler-jake-tapper-interview/index.html#&SM_LENGTH=7

However, as you can see if you visit the webpage, sometimes the webpage takes a small amount of time (up to a few seconds) to summarize the article. It's less noticeable on this article - but usually a pink loading bar will move up and down in the pink box until the summary is created and displayed on the website.

I believe my code is downloading the source of the website before it finishes summarizing the article, thus the HTML file my program downloads does not contain the summary of the article.

How can I make sure the `fetch()` request only downloads the content of the website once the website `https://smmry.com` has finished summarizing the article `https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/01/politics/ronald-kessler-jake-tapper-interview/index.html`.

Edit: My `manifest.json` file.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Summarizer",
"version": "1.0",

"description": "Summarizes webpages",

"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "downloads",
    "*://*.smmry.com/*"
],

"icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
},

"browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_popup": "popup/choose_page.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "icons/summarizer-icon-16.png",
        "32": "icons/summarizer-icon-32.png"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Just make delay while the pink loading bar is being displayed.

Comment: That is what I want to do, but I don't know how

Comment: My requirement is to fetch the content of the page (let's say 'www.abc.com/data' ) that loads the data dynamically after the whole page has been loaded. When I get the source code of the data page, it returns basic HTML, without the data, as data loading takes about 2-3 seconds. What can I do here to make the fetch() wait for about 2-3 seconds before it can come back with the response?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `document.onload`

Maybe you need make somethig like this:

```
document.onload = () => { 
    let URL = 'https://smmry.com/https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/01/politics/ronald-kessler-jake-tapper-interview/index.html#&SM_LENGTH=7'

    fetch(URL)
    .then((resp) => resp.text())
    .then(responseText => {
       download("website_source.html", responseText)
    })

    const download = (filename, text) => {

    const element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

     document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
};
```

the onload will wait for the page, and then you can make your fetch

Comment: Using ".onclick", ".onload", or "on" anything is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code; as well as limiting you to one event listener per event. Consider attaching your events with addEventListener, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: @CertainPerformance It seems like I have to use `addEventListener("load", function(){`…`})`, but what would I attach the event listener too? I'm writing this code for a Firefox/Chrome web extension.

Comment: @Roymunson It's a good habit to get into to use `addEventListener` everywhere even if you *think* you'll get away with using an `on*` property. What if some other script on the page also follows bad practices and reassigns `document.onload` itself? Best to just use `addEventListener` everywhere and forget about it

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'll use the `addEventListener`. I'm just not sure how to implement it in my code in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `addEventListener` and cleaning up the code some:

```
function main(){
  const URL = 'https://smmry.com/https://www.cnn.com/2018/04/01/politics/ronald-kessler-jake-tapper-interview/index.html#&SM_LENGTH=7'
  fetch(URL)
    .then(resp => resp.text())
    .then(responseText => download("website_source.html", responseText));

  function download(filename, text) {
    const element = document.createElement('a');
    element.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text);
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    element.remove();
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

Comment: This didn't work. I tried with the following URL: `https://smmry.com/https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/1946/08/31/hiroshima?intcid=mod-most-popular#&SM_LENGTH=7`  If you go to this URL, you will notice it takes a long time for the website to generate a summary of the article. My code is for a chrome web extension, which downloads the sources of webpages with the base domain `smmry.com` (even when the user is currently browsing a different tab, such as newyorker.com) . As such, I think the problem is that the `eventListener` is calling `main` when my extension (not the provided URL) is loaded.

Comment: I added a edit to the top of my original post that explains my problem more clearly.

Comment: Your link seems to create the summary near-immediately for me? Is it that the summaries that aren't saved in their database already don't get displayed in the downloaded HTML? Maybe you want to create a `setTimeout()`?

Comment: I know that all the summaries that the website displays are saved in the HTML, because when I manually went to that link and downloaded it, the summary was there. But, when I use `fetch()` and retrieve the source of the website, the summary isn't there. In order to create a `setTimeout()` should I just add it at the start of the `main` function?

Comment: "But, when I use fetch() and retrieve the source of the website, the summary isn't there" < this wasn't mentioned in your question and seems to be the actual problem you were trying to fix. I can see the summary in the plain HTML, but is your response blank/fails? If so, it's a CORS issue.

Comment: the response from fetch() successfully retrieves the source of the webpage, except for the part with the summary. I don't know if it is a CORS issue because I set the permissions up in my `manifest.json` (I'll add it to my post in a second) and the chrome extension (sometimes, but inconsistently) does download the source of the webpage *with* the summary inside of it.